# Custom tick marks for colormap

Tags: python, geopandas

How can I determine which numbers I would like to display on a colormap?

E.g. GeoPandas automatically displays `0.2*10^9`, `0.4*10^9`, `0.6*10^9` ... and so on. What if I just want to display `0`, `500,000,000` and`1,000,000,000` at the correct position?

```
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot(column='pop_est', legend=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parameter `legend_kwds` and pass the desired ticks as a list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot(
    column='pop_est', 
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={'ticks': [0,500000000,1000000000]}
)
plt.show()
```

[image]